# Eclipse CDT syntax error but still compiles

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I've installed the latest MinGW (8.1.0) and have tested with Eclipse Neon and Photon

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main(){
    std::unordered_map<int,std::string> dict = {{1,"one"},{2,"two"}};
    dict.insert({3,"three"});
    for(const auto& p: dict){std::cout << p.first << " = " << p.second << std::endl;}
}
```

it compiles fine, but the `insert` method is underlined red.

Eclipse gives the error: 'insert' is ambiguous

is there any way to update the eclipse indexer or something?

EDIT:
casting an argument to const removes the syntax error

```
dict.insert(std::pair<const int,std::string>{3,"three"});
```

EDIT 2:
or you can use MinGW (5.1.0) with C++11 dialect

EDIT 3:
[Eclipse Photon R](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/photon/r/eclipse-ide-cc-developers)
[GCC 7.3.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/7.3.0/threads-posix/dwarf/)

EDIT 4:
[CDT 9.5.5](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/cdt/releases/9.5/cdt-9.5.5/cdt-9.5.5.zip) for Photon ([19th Nov 2018](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.cdt/releases/9.5.5))

Eclipse 4.6 (Neon 2016) is no longer supported. (CDT 9.2)
Eclipse 4.8 (Photon 2018) is no longer supported. (CDT 9.5)
Eclipse 4.9 (2019) is now on the rise, starting with CDT 9.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue affecting GCC 8 standard library headers, tracked in [Eclipse bug 540957](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=540957). It was fixed for CDT 9.6 (released as part of Eclipse 2018-12).

**UPDATE**: The bug was also fixed for CDT 9.5.5, which is planned for an out-of-band release on 2018-11-19. If you're running Eclipse Photon or later, `Help -> Check for Updates` should pick up this update once it's out.

A workaround until then is to use GCC 7 or earlier.

Comment: thanks for the insight. for now i've found out i can just cast the argument to const `dict.insert(std::pair<const int, std::string>{3, "three"});`

Comment: Yes, there are also workarounds that involve changing the code.

Comment: i also gave GCC 7, 6, 5, 4 a test. but only GCC 5.1.0 worked (with C++11). (the same GCC codeblocks uses)

Comment: You need to make sure Eclipse is picking up the new GCC headers (e.g. F3 on `#include <unordered_map>` takes you to the right file), and then rebuild index, for a change of compiler to take effect.

Comment: i already know that, thanks. (that's obvious usage info you're giving) but you can just build and it gets the new headers. you reindex to correct the syntax. (and that's what i did to obviously check)

Comment: Ok, just checking :) For completeness, what Eclipse version where you using when you tested GCC 7?

Comment: it was Neon. but honestly it doesn't matter which. (i tested with Photon to see if gcc 8 didn't have that syntax error. this isn't about gcc.) if you know of any eclipse version that works better, let me know.

Comment: Right, so Neon is an older version that can't parse GCC 7 headers either. GCC 7 should work with Neon.1 and later.

Comment: See also my edit about the fix being released in a couple of days.

Comment: HighCommander totally wrong. i've tried with the latest Neon and latest Photon. try first and then tell me. like i said, if you KNOW any eclipse version that works, let me know. i know the current version ain't working like other ide's.

Comment: I've tried the example code from the question, with GCC 7, in Eclipse Photon, and it works fine. In Eclipse Neon it does not. I bisected the versions between Neon and Photon to see which version it started working with, and found that it started working with Neon.1, suggesting that something needed for parsing GCC 7 headers was fixed between Neon and Neon.1.

Comment: which exact GCC did you use? i686-7.3.0-release-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev0 for example?

Comment: I used GCC 7.1. It's possible that 7.1 vs. 7.3 makes a difference, but I don't have 7.3 around at the moment to test.

Comment: Update: Ok, I've built GCC 7.3, and replicated my bisection with it. Same results: the problem goes away between Neon and Neon.1.

Comment: can you give me the download link to the gcc and eclipse you're using?

Comment: I built GCC 7.3 from [this tarball](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-7.3.0/gcc-7.3.0.tar.xz), and downloaded e.g. Eclipse Photon from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/photon/R/eclipse-cpp-photon-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz).

Comment: how do i build from that? also, could you test this on windows?

Comment: On a Unix-like system, it's a pretty standard autotools build (`configure && make && make install`). May be more tricky on Windows. (WSL might make it easier?) Unfortunately, I don't have access to a Windows computer.

Comment: thanks. i was just interested. but i was able to download [GCC 7.3](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/7.3.0/threads-posix/dwarf/) from sourceforge and get the [Windows eclipse photon r](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/photon/r/eclipse-ide-cc-developers) and it's sorted. i tested with GCC 8.1 again just to test, but yeah, eclipse is pretty wonky. why can't they just make it understand from the GCC! anyway, thanks for all the assistance.

Comment: The CDT 9.5.5 update mentioned in my answer should be out now, and should work with GCC 8.

Comment: thanks a lot! i just download [CDT 9.5.5](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/cdt/releases/9.5/cdt-9.5.5/cdt-9.5.5.zip) and it works with GCC 8.1! perfect! i just hope they could do the fix for neon too. i tried it with neon, but it  couldn't fully install all the cdt 9.5.5 stuff for it. (the cdt main features)

Comment: silly me, i realize Neon is simply an outdated eclipse version. lol (Neon 2016, Oxygen 2017, Photon 2018...) and the last cdt for neon was 9.2. well. can't wait for eclipse 2019. all cdt versions are listed [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewInCDT).

Comment: Galileo (09), Helios (10), Indigo (11), Juno (12), Kepler (13), Luna (14), Mars (15), Neon (16), Oxygen (17), Photon (18), etc... the code names follow an alphabetic progression... so 2019 is Q. any guesses? lol

Comment: oh... [Eclipse Simultaneous Release](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Simultaneous_Release) "Since the 2018-09 release, the cadence changed from one annual main release plus 3 update/service releases to a 13-week cycle with rolling releases." looks like there'll be no Eclipse Queen then. lol